# Lambda Operations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have two columns hours and minutes stored separately in columns: a and b
I want to calculate the sum of both in terms of minutes(DURATION)

To convert the hour into minutes I have used the following:

```
        train['duration']=train.a.apply(lambda x:x*60)
```

Now I want to add the minutes to the newly created duration column.

```
        So that my final value is duration=(a*60)+b
```

I am unable to perform this operation using lambda and for loop takes forever to execute In pandas.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using lambda as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]})
df["sum"] = df.apply(lambda row: row.x + row.y, axis=1)
print(df)
```

It will give following output:

```
   x  y  sum
0  1  4    5
1  2  5    7
2  3  6    9
```

Hope it helps. You can do it using List Comprehension as that will be fast also or as @Karl Olufsen suggested.

Comment: You wanted using Lambda only. So, here is the way you can do.

Comment: You should assign your `df.apply()` result to a new column, otherwise this is not visible in your `print(df)`.

Comment: Ya, You are right. Thanks @Arnaud . I'll edit the answer

Comment: I'm glad that you got what you were searching for 

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a very powerful module with neat features. If you want to simply add values of 1 column to values in another respectively you can simply do + operation on the columns.
Here is my example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":[10,20,30,40]})

df["sum of 2 columns"] = df["col1"] + df["col2"]

print(df)
```

And this is the output:

```
   col1  col2  sum of 2 columns
0     1    10                11
1     2    20                22
2     3    30                33
3     4    40                44
```

Comment: Yes, but how to do the same thing using lambdas?

Comment: But why do you even need lambdas when pandas can do this out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use vectorized code which would be faster than apply

```
df['duration_in_min'] = df['hour'] * 60 + df['min']
```

The time complexity of various operations from best(fastest) to worst(slowest) is:

> Cython procedures < Vectorized code < apply < itertuples < iterrows